# Windows 8 - load shell extension immediately

Tags: windows, shell, windows-8-preview, dll

I am trying to use [Stardock Fences](http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/) with Windows 8 and I've run into an interesting problem. For those who do not know this program - let it be just one, that modifies shell. Switching to desktop (app?) doesn't load the corresponding dll or exe, however, opening right-click menu of the desktop does. Further investigation showed that this dll is classified as "Context menu" type and apparently Windows 8 loads it only "on demand" i. e. when open right-click menu.

So, how do I force this single dll to load on user log in or system startup?

Thanks in advance, I will provide any needed clarifications.

Comment: Has the company added support for Windows 8?

Comment: No it has not, however, I don't think that it would be hard to simulate that "demand", so DLL gets loaded or to load it manually, but I don't have any experience with that.

Answer (score 1):

Stardock is rather heavilly tied to how Windows works. The correct thing to do is to wait for Windows8 to be supported by Stardock and then to install the Windows8-compatible version.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fix for this issue here: http://forums.overclockers.com.au/showthread.php?t=1064237

Comment: Can you add the details to this answer as to what the fix resolves? Even if it's mostly a copy/paste from the forum post that explains the fix that's fine so long as you site it as the source. The stackexchange sites strive to have the answers be able to stand on their own without just being links to other sites.